# Replace in MySQL

Tags: mysql

In my database I have a few records like these with 2 columns:

```
 Id, Name,

11,  Meal 997,
12,  Meal 998,
13,  Meal 999,
14,  Meam 000,
15,  Meam 001,
16,  Meam 002,
```

But this was an issue in the application with the wrong data due to a logical error.
How can we change the records containing **Meam** to **Meal** and also continue incrementing?

The above records should be like these:

```
11,  Meal 997,
12,  Meal 998,
13,  Meal 999,
14,  Meal 1000,
15,  Meal 1001,
16,  Meal 1002,
```

How can we change the database?

"Meam 001" will be in one columm

What would the query be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
update tablename
set name=replace(name,'Meam','Meal 1')
where name like "Meam%"
```

you can test it with:

```
select name, replace(name,'Meam','Meal 1')
from tablename
```

;)

Comment: seems this was tricky, now it shows as "Meal 1 001", "Meal 1 002". How can we concate as "Meal 1001". thanks for your answer :)

Comment: Just change >>replace(name,'Meam','Meal 1')<< with >>replace(name,'Meam ','Meal 1')<<
NOTE THE space after Meam !

Comment: thanks a lot , now i need to focus on Mysql functions seriously :)

Answer (score 1):

Would not a simple SQL UPDATE query be enough?

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

or have I totally misunderstood the question, apologies if I have...

Answer (score 1):

```
update tablename
set name='Meal' , intvalue=concat('1',intvalue)
where name='Meam'
```

---

in the table: 
`name` is the columname of the column containing `Meal` or `Meam`.
`intvalue` is the columname of the column containing the integer number.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Dynodix, both will be in one column name ie. column Name contains "Meam 001", "Meam 002". thanks in advance