# Mass editing SQL fields?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Replace in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094300/replace-in-mysql)

I have a fields in sql database, all text. How can I edit text for all fields? For example I have the same word in all fields, and I want it change to something else or delete it completely.

Comment: Unfortunately you are going to do a little bit more reading on how MySQL works before asking a question here. Google for mysql tutorials or mysql documentation for help. Your question is far to vague and ambiguous for anyone to help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to brute force this. You have to call the UPDATE statement for every column you want to have changed. (If you really have A LOT of columns you can access the metadata of your database to gather the names of all tables and then gather the names of all columns in that tables and create your UPDATE scripts automatically.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you need another table to store your words.
So, you will be able to delete or update them using regular SQL queries.

Cannot answer more for such a vague question.

Comment: Depending on the application this would be a pain but I can definitely see how this could help! Basically a dictionary in a table! hehe