# How to Replace a Word in a MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, rename

I made a typo in a large `VARCHAR` field of a MySQL table.  How do I change the word `operaet` to `operate`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Replace in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5094300/replace-in-mysql)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all instances of `operaet` are probably typos, just run this against the entire table:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name, 'operatre','operate');
```

Comment: maybe you mean `operaet` not `operatre`.

Answer (score 0):

simply go to your structure tab and rename it. Or run this mysql command

```
UPDATE `your_table_name` SET `column_name` = REPLACE(column_name, 'operatre','operate');
```